# I am trying to make three dice roll simultaneously until they land on the number 6

Tags: java, arrays

My program is supposed to print the number of rolls before all three dice come up all sixes.

This is what I have so far, but I am getting outputs that are small numbers like 1 I do not think it can take 1 time to roll all three sixes. I am expecting larger numbers.

```
Random rand = new Random();
    int numOfRolls = 0; //starts at zero for the number of rolls
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    do {
      numOfRolls++;
      x = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
      y = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
      z = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    } while (x == 6 || y == 6 || z == 6);
    System.out.println(numOfRolls);
```

Comment: Java is not the same thing as JavaScript. This is Java. Please remember to tag correctly; I've corrected this for you. In future, please remember to only tag the **relevant** coding language(s). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the `while` condition to:

```
while (x !=6 || y != 6 || z != 6)
```

This will cause the loop to continue until all three values are 6.

Answer (score 1):

Using or's will tell you the number of rolls until ONE of the three integers lands on 6. Also you want the program to stop once it lands on three 6's so switch the == to !=.

```
x != 6 && y != 6 && z != 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Logic condition needs to be:

`while(x != 6 || y != 6 || z != 6)`

*Because you need to repeat loop until all three are not 6*

Example:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int numOfRolls = 0; //starts at zero for the number of rolls
int x;
int y;
int z;
do {
  numOfRolls++;
  x = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
  y = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
  z = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
} while (x != 6 || y != 6 || z != 6);
System.out.println(numOfRolls);
```

Comment: @Spencer happy to help, all the best :)

Comment: @A.J how did you get it to paste as a code snippet in the stack overflow editor?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : I copied code to snippet to make it tidy . It won't execute java. Removing it from snippet keeping just code now. Thanks for pointing :)

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Is your question how I used stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @A.J excellent thanks mate. btw the code snippet doesn't seem to run?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : Yeah, SO snippet is doesn't support java yet. It is only for JS, HTML, CSS yet.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Logic in Psudeo-code

you want it to continue if all three dice roll something which is NOT 6. Others have already noted it but I'll spell the logic out in psudeo-code so it should be more clear:

```
        // Do While:
        // firstDie is not 6 AND secondDie is not 6 AND thirdDie is not 6
        // if firstDie == 6 and secondDie == 6 and thirdDie == 6 then you should stop looping
```

#### The actual code

```
        // so transforming the above logic into code - change the while statement to something like this:
        while (x != 6 || y != 6 || z != 6)

        // or you can break OUT of the loop when all three die land six. something like this:
        while (true) 
        {
            // all the rest of the code setting up the values
            if ( x == 6 && y == 6 && z == 6) break;
        }
```